# Where to put resource files on Linux?

Tags: linux, compilation, makefile, convention

I'm using makefiles. I have /src, /include, /res and a makefile. The build directory is passed to make. Some of the binaries need resource files stored in /res. One way to access the resources is to tell the makefile to copy /res into the build directory. Is there a more conventional way to do this?

I prefer to have only executables in the build directory and some other directory for the resources. If one chooses, for example, /usr/bin/ for the executables, what's the convention for resource files? /usr/share/?

Answer (score 1):

```
One way to access the resources is to tell the makefile to copy /res 
into the build directory. Is there a more conventional way to do this?
```

No. Copying the resource files to the build directory isn't a wise option. Let the resource files be there in `/res` makeuse of the [`VPATH` variable in `makefile`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Directory-Search). You can assign the directory path to `VPATH` so that `make` will search for the file in that folder after searching the current folder.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear enough. The resource files are needed during runtime, like config, input files or files storing large amounts of ascii data ... they are not things I want to use during compilation.